# Flash Actionscript Timer - what happens when an event doesn't finish in time?

Tags: flash, actionscript, timer

I'm using the [Actionscript Timer class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Timer.html). What happens if I run a function every 3 seconds, but the function takes 4 seconds to complete?

Does the Timer object queue up events? I guess this must happen if only 1 thread is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the events will be fired - if the script takes more time to run than the delay, the timings will be offset as required and you will not get the desired output.

From the page you linked:

> Depending on the SWF file's framerate or Flash Player's environment (available memory and other factors), Flash Player may dispatch events at slightly offset intervals. For example, if a SWF file is set to play at 10 frames per second [fps], which is 100 millisecond intervals, but your timer is set to fire an event at 80 milliseconds, Flash Player will fire the event close to the 100 millisecond interval. Memory-intensive scripts may also offset the events.